# Pythonic way to calculate fastest distance in matrix given two coordinates?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, matrix

For example, if I have an X by Y grid of street intersections with the destination at the bottom right hand corner (position x-1,y-1). How do you calculate the distance given a matrix?

For example, if the input matrix was

```
matrix=[[1,2,1],
        [2,3,2],
        [1,2,1]]
```

If I was given coordinates (0,0), which is 1 in this case and wanted to get to (2,2), which is also 1 at the bottom right hand corner, the fastest distance is 7 (going right and down).

You could also go right one and down and then right and then down again. This is a distance of 8: 1+2+3+2+1=8.

How do you do find the shortest path? You can only move right and down. I'm trying to use a nested for loop but don't understand the logic I would have to use to do this.

Comment: Can you only move right and down (and not left and up)?

Comment: Correct, only right and down.

Comment: I must say it is a difficult question. Try recursion?

Comment: Python isn't really built for recursion but I could try that...hmm...an way to solve this via Python's powerful libraries?

Comment: You'd have to look into something like `itertools` although I doubt you'd get anything out of it.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, this problem is widely studied.  [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: Hint: The final step you take must be from one of 2 positions: in your example, either (2, 1) or (1, 2).  If you can calculate the shortest distance to both of those positions, you can quickly calculate the answer by just comparing the two costs.  So...  How do you calculate those 2 shortest distances? :)

Comment: a* is what you want ... something like this will help you understand http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/solving-mazes-using-python-simple-recursivity-and-a-search/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a problem which should be modeled as a graph problem. So, you may use an algorithm such as [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path.

You may first translate your matrix to a graph data structure (such as a adjacency matrix): Each element of your matrix is a vertex, and the value of the element is the edge cost. There is only edges between elements which are neighbors by the vertical or by the horizontal, and, in this case, this will also be a directed graph.

```
1 [[0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0],
2  [1 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0],
3  [0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0],
4  [1 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 0],
5  [0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0],
6  [0 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 1],
7  [0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0],
8  [0 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 1],
9  [0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0]]
```

After that, just use a Dijkstra Algorithm implementation, which you can implement by your self, or easily find it on the web.

Hint: If you need to find the value of the path (in the way you said above), you may also save the values of the first and of the last element and sum them with the value of the path found by the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, I know about Dijkstra's algorithm. I was thinking though that there would be a different way to solve it using Python. Thanks for the suggestion still.